# pasar una fecha de formato dia/mes/año a año/mes/dia en javascript

Tags: javascript, date

tengo una variable que me trae la informacion de un combobox la cual contiene lo siguiente

```
var a = (fecha);
// donde fecha es igual a 28/12/2021
```

lo que necesio es que a me devuelva la misma fecha pero en formato

2021/12/28

ya que despues se tiene que ingresar como

```
var newfecha =  new Date(a);
```

por que necesito ese formato para poder comparar con la fecha actual y saber cuantos dias hay entre la fecha ingresada y la actual.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo hacer primero un split() y despues convertir la cadena, por ejemplo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
var a="28/12/2021";
    var arrFecha=a.split("/");
    var fecha=new Date(arrFecha[2]+"/"+arrFecha[1]+"/"+arrFecha[0]);
    console.log(fecha);
</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me servira :)

Answer (score 2):

hice una mescla de dos foros

```
// donde fecha es igual a 28/12/2021
var a = (fecha);

//funcion que cambia las fechas de formato dia/mes/año a  año/mes/dia
function cambiarformato(string) {
        var info = string.split('-');
        return info[2] + '/' + info[1] + '/' + info[0];
    }

 var nuevafecha =convertDateFormat(a);
    console.log(nuevafecha);
var newday = new Date(nuevafecha);
    console.log(newday);
```

el valor final de newday es

Tue Dec 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer uso de [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) y [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

El primer método separa la cadena usando el token recibido como argumento y cada parte es almacenada en un Array. En este caso, podemos usar como token la barra de separación de los campos de fecha: `/`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let fecha = '2021/12/28';
let arr = fecha.split('/');
// produce: ['2021', '12', '28']
```

Una vez que tenemos el Array con los valores de año, mes y día separados, podemos usar `reverse` para invertir el orden, por ejemplo:

```js
arr.reverse();
// produce: ['28', '12', '2021']
```

Por último, volvemos a unir el Array en una cadena, usando `join` y pasamos como argumento el token de separación de fecha, por ejemplo:

```js
fecha = arr.join('/');
// produce: "28/12/2021"
```

Puedes hacerlo todo en una sola linea encadenando los métodos, por ejemplo:

```js
let fecha = '2021/12/28';
fecha = fecha.split('/').reverse().join('/');
console.log(fecha); // "28/12/2021"
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.